# STM32F722ZE SPI communication with LSM6DS33 using HAL

Tags: stm32, spi, accelerometer, hal-library, gyroscope

For a long time I can not read the correct data from the LSM6DS33 control register (accelerometer + gyroscope).

As I read in the datasheet, the control register address WHO_I_AM is 0x0f. In order to read the data, the MSB must be set to 1, so I finally send 0x8f. However, the received data has nothing to do with the expected value 0x69, I usually receive something like 0xff, 0x8f.

I check the data in debug mode, I also look directly in the DR registry. I checked all combinations of CLKPolarity, CLKPhase and nothing helped, I am convinced that everything is well connected.

I'm using TrueSTUDIO and the MXCube plugin, stm32f722ze on nucleo board

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  ** This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2018 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f7xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "stdio.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint8_t sent,received;
  sent = 0x8f;
  received =0x00;
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SSPIN_GPIO_Port,SSPIN_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,&sent,1,10);
      HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1,&received,1,10);


      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SSPIN_GPIO_Port,SSPIN_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(500);

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 216;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Activate the Over-Drive mode 
    */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SSPIN_GPIO_Port, SSPIN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : SSPIN_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SSPIN_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(SSPIN_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried to isolate the problem? Does SPI communication work with some other chip or in loopback mode? Have you got access to oscilloscope/logic analyser?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently I do not have another chip for the test. So I did loopback mode, connected the lines MISO and MOSI, modified the program and it works. I tried to run LSM6DS33 with raspberrypi and it works partially, I get data type 0x69, 0x69,0x69, 0xff, 0xff, 0x69. I do not currently have a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.

Comment: I use Pololu board (Pololu item #: 2736) with LSM6DS33.

Comment: Strange. Can you confirm SS pin is correct and properly wired (just create a "blinky" on that pin, and measure with voltmeter at LSM6DS33)? Is LSM6DS33 in SPI mode? You can also try lowering the clock although it looks it should be fine.

Comment: The SS pin is correctly connected and I checked it according to the instructions. In the case of raspberry pi, probably one wire was a bit loose but now it is okay and it reads the data 0x69 correctly .... However, on stm I also checked the SS pin - it works correctly but the data is completely random. When the SS pin is in high state spi  is in idle mode, when SS pin is in low state SPI starts send data.
The spi communication can not be disabled in the given module. It is possible to SPI / I2C active (default), or only active SPI.

Comment: `SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE`? If you disconnect MISO, do you still get random data, or 0xff as expected?

Comment: "hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_ENABLE;", I did not change it it was the default value. When I disconnect MISO spi1 dr register value is 0x00.

Comment: Well, try changing that to disabled, since you're manually controlling SS. If that doesn't change anything, try lowering the clock?

Comment: @R.Griffin - Hi, Thanks for coming back to add your solution. :-) *However*, adding the solution *into the question* is not how answers are written on Stack Exchange sites. If you have solved your own problem, then you can write your own answer :-) Therefore can you please *write your solution into your own answer* and then remove it from the question? Thanks. :-) Finally, please *accept* one of the answers, so the site knows the question has been solved. It is possible to accept your own answer. If the other answer did also work, I would encourage you to *at least upvote it*.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice, it seemed strange to write a separate answer and then accept :) Anyway, I did as  you recommended. Unfortunately, I can not upvote because I have too few reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped setting the CPOL to 'low'. I do not know why it did not work the first time, but this time I connected the sensor on the other side (to male pins)

Answer (score 1):

STM parts usually expect bursted reads with first word as address and second byte dummy. Try making your TX/RX data into arrays and doing `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` instead:

```
uint8_t txBuf[2] = {0x8f, 0x00};
uint8_t rxBuf[2] = {0x00, 0x00};
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, &txbuf, &rxBuf, 2, 10);
```

Your response should be in the second byte ([1]) of the response array.

Check section 6.2.1 of LSM6DS33 datasheet

Comment: It works, but my solution should work too, because SSPIN is still in a low state.

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Practically the chip might have some internal frame-wait timeout. I.e. if next clock does not arrive within 2-4 full clock periods, consider previous burst done, or something like that. To get details on that you should contact manufacturer.

I looked in the datasheet and did not find any info on validity duration of a single frame.